# Select from list 2 fields and join them as string

Tags: c#, string, linq, join

I have class `Product`

```
public class Product
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public int Quantity{get;set;}
   // and other
}
```

After some operation i get `List<Product>`.

How can i create string in format `productName1(productQuantity1), productName2(productQuantity2), ...` from that list?

I supposed to use `String.Join` but can't get how to use it with some dynamic object or KeyValuePair (If i use `Select` to get such objects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String.Join(", ", list.Select(p => String.Format("{0}({1})", p.Name, p.Quantity)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Join(", ", products.Select(p=>string.Format("{0}({1})",p.Name, p.Quantity)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible way:

Override `ToString()` function in `Product` class: (implementation only)

```
return string.Format("{0}({1})", Name, Quantity);
```

then write:

```
string.join (",", products.Select(p => p.ToString()));
```